# What does the name “muglue” mean?

Tags: tex-core, tex-general, glue

I'm wondering what **muglue** means in LaTeX and what it is an abbreviation/acronym of: m/u/glue. I have some idea though what glue in LaTeX means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From *The TeXbook* (my emphasis):

> [. . .] they are defined in terms of `muglue`, a special
>   brand of glue intended for math spacing. You specify `muglue` just
>   as if it were ordinary glue, except that the units are given in terms of
>   **`mu` (math units)** instead of `pt` or `cm` or something else.

As requested, also from *The TeXbook*:

> [image: Dangerous bend] There are 18 mu to an em, where the em is taken from family 2
>   (the math symbols family). In other words, `\textfont` `2` defines the em
>   value for `mu` in display and text styles; `\scriptfont` `2` defines the
>   em for script size material; and `\scriptscriptfont` `2` defines it for
>   scriptscript size.

which means that a mu unit is computed from the current math symbols font, which respects the current math style (*i.e.*, a mu unit is smaller in subscripts and even smaller in sub-subscripts), this is what makes it ideal for use in math: the spacing will be proportional, so to speak, to the font size.

Also, both LaTeX and Plain TeX define these quantities in terms of mu units:

```
\thinmuskip = 3mu % \,
\medmuskip = 4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu % \>
\thickmuskip = 5mu plus 5mu % \;
```

Comment: You might want to add that `mu` depends on the current font, as it is 1/18 em, and  that, for instance, `\thinspace` is 3mu.

Comment: @Bernard It corresponds to 1/18 em in the symbol font (family 2) of the current math style.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for this clarification!

Comment: @Bernard Done :-) (actually, that's `\thinmuskip`; `\thinspace` is a `\kern .16667em` in text-mode)